# How to do this division involving radicals, by hand?

Tags: radicals, fractions

Is it possible to perform this division by hand?
$$ x= \dfrac{2\sqrt{6} - \sqrt{30} + 14\sqrt{5} - 43}{2\sqrt{30} + 2 - 3\sqrt{6}-3\sqrt{5}} = 4 + \sqrt{5} + 2\sqrt{6} $$
If so, how? And is this possible for any general division involving multiple radicals, or this one is possible just because of its beautiful simplification?

I suspect that the $\sqrt{30}$ is of some significance, but I don't know how. I verified this here: [Wolfram Alpha result](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(2%E2%88%9A(6)+-+%E2%88%9A(30)+%2B+14%E2%88%9A(5)-43)%2F(2%E2%88%9A(30)+%2B+2+-+3%E2%88%9A(6)+-+3%E2%88%9A(5))). For those who are curious, it is the $x$-coordinate of the orthocentre of triangle $ABC$ where $A=(2\sqrt 6,1),\;B=(4,3),\;C=(\sqrt 5, 2\sqrt 5)$. Thankfully, it was I multiple choice test and I just objective'd it, but I just got curious, so I asked.

Comment: You could let $x=a+ b\sqrt{5}+c\sqrt{6}+d\sqrt{30}$ then identify the coefficients and solve for $a,b,c,d\,$.

Comment: 30 = 6x5.  So root (30) is root (6)root (5).  Just multiply top and bottom by root (6) then top and bottom by root 5.  If you have if you end up with $a +\sqrt {b} $ in the denominatot, multiply top and bottom by $a - \sqrt {b} $ that leaves $a^2-b$ on the bottom.

Comment: @fleablood Multiplying top and bottom by √6 gets me back where I was! There is still a rational term, a √6 term, a √5 term and a √30 term. How would it help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your denominator has $4$ or fewer square root terms, you can "rationalize" using $$\begin{align*}
& (a\sqrt{A}+b\sqrt{B}+c\sqrt{C}+d\sqrt{D})(a\sqrt{A}+b\sqrt{B}-c\sqrt{C}-d\sqrt{D})\\
&=a^2A+b^2B+2ab\sqrt{AB}-c^2C-d^2D-2cd\sqrt{CD}
\end{align*}$$
to reduce it to $2$ square root terms. Now the denominator would have the form $x+y\sqrt{Y}+z\sqrt{Z}$, which you can "rationalize" using

$$(x+y\sqrt{Y}+z\sqrt{Z})(x+y\sqrt{Y}-z\sqrt{Z})=x^2+y^2Y+2xy\sqrt{Y}-z^2Z.$$

Then the denominator has the form $u+v\sqrt{V}$, which you "rationalize" as 
$$(u+v\sqrt{V})(u-v\sqrt{V})=u^2-v^2V.$$
Now you have an integer denominator, but what about the numerator?

Because at the beginning you have only $5$, $6$, and $30$ in radicals, and because $\sqrt{5}\sqrt{6}=\sqrt{30}$, $\sqrt{6}\sqrt{30}=6\sqrt{5}$, and $\sqrt{30}\sqrt{5}=5\sqrt{6}$, this process of multiplying numerator and denominator by the conjugates above will leave your numerator at each step as a linear combination of $1$, $\sqrt{5}$, $\sqrt{6}$, and $\sqrt{30}$ with integer coefficients.  So the process here isn't as bad as the general case, although still tedious to do "by hand".  The coefficients in the end will not generally be multiples of the integer denominator, but if they are then your answer will work out as in your question.

Here it is actually quite simpler than the general version indicated above if you start trying to implement it. The first step would be multiplying top and bottom by $2\sqrt{30} + 2 + 3\sqrt{6}+3\sqrt{5}$, but then you are left only with $x+y\sqrt{30}$, so you can skip to step $3$.  This simplification will occur whenever your starting point is the less general $a\sqrt{A}+b\sqrt{B}+c\sqrt{AB}+d$.

---

Added: Here's another approach that will work in this $\sqrt A$, $\sqrt B$, $\sqrt{AB}$ case, which is an elaboration of [the comment by dxiv](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2200831/how-to-do-this-division-involving-radicals-by-hand#comment4528114_2200831).: By awareness that a process exists (as above) that will reduce your final answer to something of the form $a\sqrt{5}+b\sqrt{6}+c\sqrt{30}+d$, where $a$,$b$, $c$, and $d$ are rational numbers, you can just put that expression on the right hand side of your equation, multiply both sides of the equation by your denominator, group like terms, and match coefficients to solve for $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$.  A solution exists (which we know from the process above), and it is unique by linear independence of $\{1,\sqrt5,\sqrt6,\sqrt{30}\}$.

Comment: Well, I'm happy to tell you that I tried it and got it right! And you were right, the denominator remains very simple, just the numerator was diabolical. But it all ended well! Thanks for your answer! :)

Comment: Just an afterthought, it seems this would work for any number of radicals in the denominator. For example, 5 radicals could be reduced to 4 by grouping in terms of 3 and 2. What do you think?

Comment: Let's see, if you group in terms of $m$ and $n$ then you could generally end up with ${m\choose 2}+{n\choose 2}$ square root terms if you start with $m+n$ terms, and that doesn't count the non square root term.  It might work for $5$, but for $6$ or larger it looks like it is already hopeless by this method in general, but could work when many of the roots are products of other ones so the total number of different roots can't blow up as quickly.

Comment: "blow up as quickly" in my previous comment doesn't make much sense, but hopefully the overall intent is clear enough.  Some additional structure would have to exist for the number of square root terms to decrease with $6$ or more terms.